# error reading Environmental variables in C

Tags: c, windows, environment-variables

I am trying to read an environment variable on windows platform.
I made the variable global as I intend to use it through various function.
This is what I tried

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <malloc.h>
#include <string.h>

char* devset = getenv("DEVSET"); //1 for debugging, 0 for normal execution
```

I get the error

```
C:\Users\Prateek\Documents\Script Parser\main.c|6|error: initializer element is not constant
```

I tried the same thing in main, it compiled and I didn't get any errors.
However this way I will be required to pass the environmental variable as an argument to all the functions.
Is there another approach to make the environment variable globally accessible?
Any help appreciated.

Comment: You can't call a function at file scope. Put it in a function such as `main()`, and it'll work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is not with reading the environment variable, it's the place where you do it. Your code reads the variable in a static initializer, which is not allowed: only compile-time constants can be used there.

> However this way I will be required to pass the environmental variable as an argument to all the functions

No, you wouldn't: keep the variable in the global scope, and move your code into `main` to fix the problem:

```
char* devset;
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    devset = getenv("DEVSET"); //1 for debugging, 0 for normal execution
    ....
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Any global variable you initialize outside of a function must have a constant initializer. That is, the value you initialize with must be known at compile-time.

But here you're trying to call `getenv("DEVSET")`, you can't do that at compile time.

Instead, put the initialization in your main:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <malloc.h>
#include <string.h>

char* devset;

int main() {
    devset = getenv("DEVSET");
    // Your code here
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`getenv` is a function that takes a `char*` as a parameter. You are trying to call a function in global scope. This is not possible. Simply use

```
char* devset;
```

in global scope and

```
devset=getenv("DEVSET");
```

from `main`.